# MSBuild not copying a DLL, while Visual Studio does

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

In our Visual Studio 2010 project we reference - among the others - the `SmartAssembly.Attributes.dll` and it's properly copied to the `Bin/Debug` or `Bin/Release` folder of our local dev machines. On the build server this is true for all other references but not for 'SmartAssembly.Attributes.dll'. The build succeeds.

What should I check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open your `.csproj` file (or `.vbproj` file), and look for the assembly reference. Then make sure the hint path is still valid in your build server. Sometimes VS2010 will add an absolute hint path, instead of using one relative to the `.csproj` file itself, so the drive letter may be invalid in another machine.

For example, the reference may look similar to the one below (I made up all of the XML below to illustrate only and it's NOT valid), and the absolute hint path may be invalid in the build server (e.g. there's no drive letter *d* there):

```
<Reference
Include="SmartAssembly.Attributes, Version=8.0.0.0, 
       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f1f7f1ad5da3a,
       processorArchitecture=x86"> 
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>true<Private>

  <!-- The HintPath below should exist and be valid in your build server -->
  <HintPath>d:\temp\SmartAssembly.Attributes.dll<HintPath>
</Reference>
```

You can change the HintPath to make it relative to the `.csproj` file and therefore more general. For example:

```
  <HintPath>..\libs\SmartAssembly.Attributes.dll<HintPath>
```

Another problem may be that `<Private>true<Private>` isn't there. This attribute mapped to the `CopyLocal` property in Visual Studio, so if it's missing from your `.csproj`, the DLL won't get copied to `bin\Debug` or `bin\Release` by MSBuild. See http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2009/06/project-reference-fun-and-games.html

Comment: Thanks Diego, it's just what we are doing `<HintPath>..\Bin\SmartAssembly.Attributes.dll</HintPath>`

Comment: I added a comment. I think you may be missing `<Private>true<Private>`.

Comment: None of the DLLs we reference have this `<Private>true<Private>` attribute and they all are copied...

Comment: I would try it anyway. See http://bronumski.blogspot.com/2009/06/project-reference-fun-and-games.html

Comment: If "Private" is not defined, it IDE defaults to true.  However, forcing the entry in there helps with build issues.

Comment: If Private is not defined, the IDE defaults it to true - but msbuild may choose not to treat it as copylocal, because of the assembly's presence in the GAC on the build server.